# Как смешать два фоновых изображения, повторяющееся и не повторяющееся?

Tags: html, css, css3, изображения, sass

Мне нужно смешать два изображения (в multiply режиме), насколько я понял это можно сделать только используя фоновые изображения.

Как смешать два фоновых изображения , если одно изображение не должно повторяться, а другое должно (это узор)?

Как это сделать с помощью SASS (CSS)?

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/WxBbWN?editors=0110  вот так вроде бы , но я ещё чуток паралакса добавил для красоты

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    background: url('http://feelgrafix.com/data_images/out/12/859723-nature-background.jpg') no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
body:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('https://appzumbi.com/pd/e/grey-pattern-background-rectangle-fbcn.png');
}
```